# how to find records created on a certain day (not today!) in rails using postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How can I find all records created on a certain date (that has nothing to do with today or yesterday etc.)

Here's the format it's in:
    irb(main):016:0> SourceNode.first.created_at

And I want to find those that were created on 7/1/13:

```
=> Fri, 12 Jul 2013 01:15:48 UTC +00:00
irb(main):017:0> SourceNode.where("created_at = '2013-07-01'").count
=> 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's always a specific date, you could truncate the date for comparison.

```
SourceNode.where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = '2013-07-01'").count
```

Source: Postgres's excellent [date/time documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: you can safely pass in the date you're looking for as a parameter with `Obj.where("date_tunc('day', created_at) = ?", date_value)`

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, "created_at" is a datetime attribute, so it won't be equal to only a date. What I think you could do is compare if the value is between 1 second before the date and 1 second after:

```
SourceNode.where("created_at > '2013-01-06 23:59:59' AND created_at < '2013-01-08 00:00:00'")
```

Maybe there's a better way, but this worked here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, should work

```
SourceNode.where(:created_at => DateTime.parse("2013-10-31").beginning_of_day..DateTime.parse("2013-10-31").end_of_day)
```